# Power Query - Variable Column and Header location from 30+ workbooks

Tags: excel, null, header, powerquery

I am trying to combine many workbooks with multiple sheets. The issue is on sheet 1 there is a large information header prior to the information needed to extract. As well as many merged cells that return a large number of nulls and push data into variable columns depending on the date and version of the source workbooks.

Currently sorting and promoting headers allows me to match up the first Two Columns of information needed but subsequent info is pushed right into other fields.

Is there a way to delete nulls and shift the data sets left to match fields? Or better yet identify dynamic header changes and return data to match the selected headers?

Below is an outline of the issue, unfortunately cleaning the data on the amount of sheets and workbooks isn't really an option. I'm fairly new to Power Query and can't seem to figure this one out.

```
c1    c2    c3    c4   c5    c6    c7
A     B    Null   C    D    Null   E
a     b    c      D    Null  E     Null
A     B    C     Null  D     G     E
```

Need A-B-C-D-E only.

```
= () => let
    Source = Folder.Files("C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\Desktop\Log"),
    #"Filtered Hidden Files1" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),
    #"Invoke Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Hidden Files1", "Transform File from Log", each #"Transform File from Log"([Content])),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Invoke Custom Function1", {"Name", "Source.Name"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Renamed Columns1", {"Source.Name", "Transform File from Log"}),
    #"Expanded Table Column1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Transform File from Log", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transform File from Log"(#"Sample File"))),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Table Column1",{{"Source.Name", type text}, {"Name", type text}, {"Data", type any}, {"Item", type text}, {"Kind", type text}, {"Hidden", type logical}}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Data", "Name", "Source.Name"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Other Columns", each ([Name] = "page 1" or [Name] = "page 2" or [Name] = "page 2 +" or [Name] = "page 3 +" or [Name] = "page 4 +" or [Name] = "page 5 +" or [Name] = "page 6 +" or [Name] = "page 7 +" or [Name] = "page 8 +")),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Source.Name", "Name", "Data"}),
    #"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Reordered Columns", "Data", {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "Column10", "Column11", "Column12", "Column13", "Column14", "Column15", "Column16", "Column17", "Column18", "Column19", "Column20", "Column21", "Column22", "Column23", "Column24", "Column25", "Column26", "Column27", "Column28", "Column29", "Column30", "Column31", "Column32", "Column33", "Column34", "Column35", "Column36", "Column37", "Column38", "Column39", "Column40", "Column41", "Column42", "Column43", "Column44", "Column45", "Column46", "Column47", "Column48", "Column49", "Column50", "Column51", "Column52", "Column53", "Column54", "Column55", "Column56", "Column57", "Column58", "Column59", "Column60", "Column61", "Column62", "Column63", "Column64", "Column65", "Column66", "Column67", "Column68", "Column69", "Column70", "Column71", "Column72", "Column73", "Column74", "Column75", "Column76", "Column77", "Column78", "Column79", "Column80", "Column81", "Column82", "Column83", "Column84"}, {"Data.Column1", "Data.Column2", "Data.Column3", "Data.Column4", "Data.Column5", "Data.Column6", "Data.Column7", "Data.Column8", "Data.Column9", "Data.Column10", "Data.Column11", "Data.Column12", "Data.Column13", "Data.Column14", "Data.Column15", "Data.Column16", "Data.Column17", "Data.Column18", "Data.Column19", "Data.Column20", "Data.Column21", "Data.Column22", "Data.Column23", "Data.Column24", "Data.Column25", "Data.Column26", "Data.Column27", "Data.Column28", "Data.Column29", "Data.Column30", "Data.Column31", "Data.Column32", "Data.Column33", "Data.Column34", "Data.Column35", "Data.Column36", "Data.Column37", "Data.Column38", "Data.Column39", "Data.Column40", "Data.Column41", "Data.Column42", "Data.Column43", "Data.Column44", "Data.Column45", "Data.Column46", "Data.Column47", "Data.Column48", "Data.Column49", "Data.Column50", "Data.Column51", "Data.Column52", "Data.Column53", "Data.Column54", "Data.Column55", "Data.Column56", "Data.Column57", "Data.Column58", "Data.Column59", "Data.Column60", "Data.Column61", "Data.Column62", "Data.Column63", "Data.Column64", "Data.Column65", "Data.Column66", "Data.Column67", "Data.Column68", "Data.Column69", "Data.Column70", "Data.Column71", "Data.Column72", "Data.Column73", "Data.Column74", "Data.Column75", "Data.Column76", "Data.Column77", "Data.Column78", "Data.Column79", "Data.Column80", "Data.Column81", "Data.Column82", "Data.Column83", "Data.Column84"}),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Data", each ([Data.Column2] <> null and [Data.Column2] <> 16 and [Data.Column2] <> "16" and [Data.Column2] <> "LOCATION")),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Filtered Rows1", [PromoteAllScalars=true])
in
    #"Promoted Headers"
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyJAX.png)

Comment: Please elaborate on the example. What does "I need A-B-C...only" means. I suggest you show the before and after of a couple of files. Dummy data is ok.

Comment: A-B-C-D data would be town, street name, an identifying character, long/lat and a comment field. There is other data populated in the sheets that isn't needed in the final extract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of nulls and slide everything to the left

[image]

add column .. index column

right click index column, unpivot other columns

right click and remove attribute column

Group on Index and add another index in each group by modifying the code to end with

```
each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index2", 1, 1), type table}})
```

Expand the column using arrows atop, for the [x]values and [x] index2 fields

Click the Index2 field and transform .. pivot column, with Value as Values, advanced, do not aggregate

Sample code for transforming above BEFORE table to AFTER table

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index", {"Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),
#"Grouped Rows"  = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Index"}, {{"GRP", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index2", 1, 1), type table}}),
#"Expanded GRP" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "GRP", {"Value", "Index2"}, {"Value", "Index2"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded GRP", {{"Index2", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded GRP", {{"Index2", type text}}, "en-US")[Index2]), "Index2", "Value"),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index"})
in #"Removed Columns1"
```

Comment: This is perfect. The last thing is I am not sure how to account for is "Value C" missing from a few of the workbooks which still causes a skew of data. 
Best to cleanup with an conditional Column I assume? 

Thank you!!

Comment: Cant tell without seeing source data samples

Comment: If this solved your issue please accept the answer using the check toggle next to the up/down vote buttons

Comment: Thank you! 
I had it up and running but after adding more input files I am returning a DataFormat.Error: Invalid cell value '#VALUE!'. during the Grouped Rows stage. Can't seem to track where the error is coming from. The data set is pretty large.

Comment: narrow it down to the specific input file that breaks it, then look at the raw data to see how to filter it before it hits that step

Comment: Its more than just one input file returning a #VALUE! error, 14+ files of 100+. I tried remove errors and replacing values to a space or null and that doesn't seem to fix the error return. Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Take the error file and try to isolate the rows causing the issue, by using Table.RemoveLastN() or similar to keep processing more and more rows until you hit it

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible. There are 17k rows in this data set.

Comment: First try around, you do half (rows 0-9000).  if Works then try rows 9000-13000 else try rows 0-4500.  Now you have narrowed it down to 1/4 of the original.  Try a few more times and you will have a few hundred to look at